# How to change html text from jQuery return value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I have client and server code below. The functional I want to get is the web page display word "color" match the color return from the server by jQuery ajax calling. But the web page word "color" never change. Please help me out. many thanks.

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        refreshColor();

        $("#def").click(refreshColor);
    });

    function refreshColor() {
        $.get("Home/Color", function updateColor(data) {
            $("def").text(data);
            $("#def").css("color", data);
        });
    }

</script>


<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

    <span id="def">SomeColor</span>

</body>
</html>

----------------------------

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MvcApplication1.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public string Color()
        {
            string[] color = { "red", "blue", "black", "green", "brown" };

            Random rd = new Random();

            var c = color.Skip(rd.Next(5)).First();

            return c;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: looks like you just missed the `#` in `$('def').text`. As such it appears to be a simple typographic error, which is off-topic for [SO].

Comment: I do not agree with you. Thought it is a simple error, it still can cause big issue. Many plane crash was just by a tiny part damaged.

Comment: @Matthew Sure, but that is not the point. The point is that reading this question and its answers will probably not be useful for others, and for you, the problem has already been solved. So who benefits from reopening the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simple syntax error in

```
$("def").text(data);
```

use this

```
$("#def").text(data);
```

Comment: Thanks Govind, your answer is correct. It is my typing mistake.

Answer (score 2):

selector syntax wrong, it should be:

```
$("#def").text(data);
   ^
   |
   |
$("#def").css("color", data);
```

Comment: This answer is a great reason to close. Please cast your vote.

Comment: ok sure @JanDvorak...